# Use .NET 4.5 assemblies inside a .NET 2.0 Project?

Tags: .net

We have some legacy code.  We need that legacy code to be able to use some DTOs that lie inside a .NET 4.5 project.

I assume that adding an assembly or project reference (either or) to the project that is .NET 4.5 that contains DTOs I want to use in my .NET 2.0 project is not gonna work.  Or can it?  If the app runs under the .NET 2.0 framework I assume that you can't have dll references higher than the .NeT 2.0 framework as part of your solution.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: this is not one that requires code, it's a general compatibility question.  I am simply asking if you can take a .NET 4.5 dll and stick it into a project using .NET 2.0...probably obviously not but just checking to see if people have been able to somehow do this.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You cannot reference .NET 4.5 dlls in a .NET 2 project.